# SubMenu in C# using WindowsForm?

Tags: c#, arrays, split, submenu, menustrip

I have a menustrip consists of Menu and Tools

in "Menu" i have subMenus like msO1,msO2,msO3......., and on "Tools" i have subMenus like msP1,msP2,msP3.......,

on Form load all the subMenus visible is false..., On button Click user want to select which subMenus he want...,

in the textBox(txtSelect) if user enter 1,3..., he get msO1, msO3.....,

my code is a hardcode..., if i have 20 subMenus means this code is not helpfull anybody have an idea...,

```
   private void btnSelect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msO1.Visible = false;//msO1 is a submenu
        msO2.Visible = false;
        msO3.Visible = false;
        msP1.Visible = false;
        msP2.Visible = false;
        msP3.Visible = false;
        string word = txtSelect.Text;
        string[] splt = word.Split(',');
        int[] arrayItms = new int[splt.Length];
        for (int x = 0; x < splt.Length; x++)
        {
            arrayItms[x]=Convert.ToInt32(splt[x].ToString());
            if (splt.Length > 0)
            {
                switch (arrayItms[x])
                {
                    case 1:
                        msO1.Visible = true; break;
                    case 2:
                        msO2.Visible = true; break;
                    case 3:
                        msO3.Visible = true; break;
                    case 4:
                        msP1.Visible = true; break;
                    case 5:
                        msP2.Visible = true; break;
                    case 6:
                        msP3.Visible = true; break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: if i have 20 subMenus means this code is not helpfull anybody have an idea...,Because it is too lengthy...,

Comment: So you want to make the code cleaner and shorter?

Comment: yes....,Your are correct...,I don't get any idea i am thinking for that

Comment: Ive added my answer below.

Comment: you could do this in several ways for example you could check to see what value of the Menu Name + 1 ,2 ,3 ect bacically name the menu SubItems like ms1 - ms20 and you can do a Foreach loop on the Controls and passing into a method the number or numbers that were entered into the textbox, then set them visible. it beats writing 20 case statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of your MenuStrip

```
MenuStrip[] mstrip = new MenuStrip[] 
{
    msO1,msO2, msO3, msP1, msP2, msP3 // add other menus here when needed
};
```

now you could work on the array as a Whole to make visible or not your menus

```
   for(int x = 0; x < menus.Length; x++)
      mstrip[x].Visible = false;
```

and your code could be simplified with

```
    for (int x = 0; x < splt.Length; x++)
    {
        int menuIndex;
        if(Int32.TryParse(splt[x], out menuIndex))
        {
            menuIndex--;
            if(menuIndex >= 0 && menuIndex < mstrip.Length)
                mstrip[menuIndex].Visible = true;
       }
    }
```

Remember, arrays indexes start at zero (while your user will probably start counting a 1).

Comment: Steve much cleaner Idea you have provided but I still can't see where the example will take advantage of multiple items that need to be Visible if the user enters `1,3,5` in the TextBox

Comment: @Steve are you missing this `string[] splt = txtSelect.Text.Split(',');`

Comment: Yes, this is a replacement for its inner loop

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each ToolStripMenuItem control in the menu strip items and set them to visible.
You can add further conditions inside the loop to define which of the menu items should be made visible based on the users choice..

```
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mi in menuStrip1.Items)
        {
            mi.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: this works for all of them re-read his question.. what if the user enters 1,3,5 in the Textbox? then you need to make visible / enable only those 3 items

Comment: user can select what ever submenus he want in the textbox....., based on the textBox i want to show the subMenus..,

Comment: You add the conditions inside the loop as to whether the item matches the users requests!

Comment: you should perhaps state that otherwise I am afraid the OP may take the code literally

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
    string word = txtSelect.Text;
    string[] splt = word.Split(',');
    for (int x = 0; x < splt.Length; x++)
    {
       Control myControl1 = FindControl("ms" + splt[x]);
       if ( myControl1 != null )
         (ToolStripMenuItem)myControl1.Visible = true;
    }
```

Untested but this should get you half way there I hope.